# Какого рода слово куки (cookie) в русском языке?

Tags: морфология, заимствования, существительные, род

Какого рода слово куки (cookie) в русском языке?

Куки (англ. cookie, буквально — печенье) — небольшой фрагмент данных, отправленный веб-сервером и хранимый на компьютере пользователя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В академических словарях это слово не зафиксировано. Носители языка даже не пришли пока к единому мнению по вопросу склоняемое оно или нет. Но, судя по всем известным мне случаям, оно употребляется только во множественном числе. В таком случае естественно считать, что оно не имеет рода, как и все другие подобные существительные (ножницы, каникулы, сани и т.д.).